# Issues with Spark Serialization?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-sql

Let be a job that contains two phases that (for convenience) cannot be merged. Let's call `A` the first step and `B` the second step. Hence, we always need to do `A` then `B`.

**Workflow**

- start new cluster with a job `A`
- build `MyOutput`
- `count(MyOutput)` = 2000 (*)
- `write(MyOutput)`
- start new cluster with a job `B`
- `read(MyOutput)`
- `count(MyOutput)` = 1788 (**).

**Precisions**

- `A` provides an output which is an `RDD[MyObject]`, namely `MyOutput`. To write `MyOutput`, here is what I do: `MyOutput.saveAsObjectFile("...")`
- Then `B` uses `MyOutput` as an input, reading the previously written file. Here is what I do: `val MyOutput: RDD[MyObject] = sc.objectFile("...")`
- `A` and `B` happen on two separate clusters.

**Problem**

The main point is that the problem does not ALWAYS happen but when this problem appears, `(*) < (**)` -- it seems we lost some data whereas we should not have any differences between these data. Obvisously something is wrong.

Do you know what happens here? How to solve that?